# How do I put a swift package in Edit Mode?

Tags: swift-package-manager, xcode11

So I want to edit some files in a swift package in Xcode 11.0 beta (11M336w) on MacOS 10.15 Beta (19A471t).

Let's take https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader as an example.

It has an example app which uses the repo from GitHub.
Suppose I want to make some source code changes. How do I tell the system I want to edit the package?

I tried "`swift package edit NFCPassportReader`" on the command line.

1. If I run it from the example app's root folder I get "`error: root
   manifest not found`"
2. If I run it from the root of the package I get "`error: Could not
   find dependency 'NFCPassportReader'`"

What steps do I need to take for get the package in edit mode (in Xcode 11), and from which directory?

P.s. Here is the Package.swift file from the repo

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "NFCPassportReader",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "NFCPassportReader",
            targets: ["NFCPassportReader"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "NFCPassportReader",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "NFCPassportReaderTests",
            dependencies: ["NFCPassportReader"]),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you clone a package locally and drag it into your project or workspace, that local copy will override the (read-only) remote dependency anywhere it was referenced. You can then edit the local copy of the package as needed.

You can see more on this workflow about 23 minutes into the WWDC2019 video for Creating Swift Packages: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/

Comment: I did this & wasn't able to alter the dragged-in local clone's target membership to get it working with my project.

Comment: If anyone can not make the swift package editable, restart the Xcode and drag it again. (Xcode Version 11.3 beta)

Comment: There is an XCode bug. If the dragged package is open on XCode, it doesn't work. Make sure it is closed before you drag it to another XCode project or swift package.

Comment: Also, if it doesn't work, make sure the directory's name is identical with package repository name (not the package name set in Package.swift file).

Comment: Restarting Xcode after dragging the local package + adding target worked for me

Comment: it doesn't work at all. Swift package appears in sources but not in swift package list. And you get a lot of errors. Why is it accepted as an answer?

Comment: Something I noticed is that, firstly, regular Package Dependencies adding was done already, and without anything else, like reverting it, immediately drag-and-drop into Xcode bundle happened, keeping its target intact, and re-bundle the package to be editable. Until I noticed this, I had hard time replicating what the WWDC video was doing (@Gargo)