# Streamlining working on project spread across multiple packages in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode11

I have my codebase spread across several swift packages for the sake of modularity and faster compile times. While Xcode 11 beta now has official support for packages, managing personal code distributed among several packages seems to be as difficult as ever.

Say I'm working on package A which has package B as a dependency. B is 98% complete, and so I almost never touch it. But for the 2% when A requires some minor change to B, I have to go through the whole rigmarole of 1) open project B in Xcode, 2) make minor change 3) commit minor change 4) tag minor change (otherwise it won't get picked up) 5) push minor change. 6) go back to A, update to latest package versions.

Sometimes the minor change in question is as minor as making a method public so package A can use it. This is literally a 1-word change.

Are there any shortcuts that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode’s workflow for editing packages makes this easier, as answered here: [How do I put a swift package in Edit Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627369/how-do-i-put-a-swift-package-in-edit-mode/56641364#56641364)